# Audits in Vote Summary page

Tags: support, review-audits, timeline

Just noticed, that [my question timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66707854/timeline) has audit related items:

> [image: Audit]

Why is this needed? Was there any announcement about the change in the timeline?

Comment: A post appearing in a review queue can explain additional activity/attention. Checking the review history of a post can be useful to track problems regarding review or curation. I don't think this changed recently.

Comment: @yivi I never noticed that before, but worth noting that I'm not watching timelines regularly in SO. Is it related to SO only, but not other SE sites?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ it's there on SE sites with review audits enabled, which are [only a few](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/241919).

Comment: @AndrewT. despite Stack Overflow in Russian in that list I have never seen this on that site.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ I think I found [one](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/511086/timeline). (P.S. the comment on [your MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361536/241919) might help finding more)